# Bower "MODULE_NOT_FOUND Cannot find module 'qs'"

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

No matter what I do, I keep getting the message:

> bower MODULE_NOT_FOUND      Cannot find module 'qs'

Whenever I try to install a package with bower.

NPM version 1.4.14
Bower version 1.3.8
Node Version 0.10.29

Anyone have any idea what I can do to fix? I'm running out of ideas at this point, I've tried reinstalling node, downgrading NPM (from 1.5.0 Beta 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the NODE_PATH environment variable. This is needed when you install modules in a local context.

```
export NODE_PATH=${PWD}/node_modules
```

http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

Comment: OK, that worked. But that doesn't seem "right". I didn't have to do this before, and now I (seemingly randomly) do sometimes. Somethings wrong here...

Answer (score 6):

I solve this by reinstalling bower by npm.

`npm install bower -g`

Comment: This should be the best answer. Thank you!

Comment: Turned out to be a deprecated version of `bower` - reinstalling it solved it.

Comment: All versions of bower are deprecated; the proper solution is to uninstall them all.